# PHP: dynamic $this->class->function

Tags: php, oop

I was wondering if there is such a thing like dynamic Class and Function calling possible?

For example, I have these two operations:

```
$this->foo->value();

$this->bar->value();
```

and I would like to call it somewhat like this:

```
$this->($var)->value();
```

right now I'm doing it this way (but would love the above methode)

```
if($var == 'foo')
    $this->foo->value(); 
else 
    $this->bar->value();
```

Comment: PHP is interpreted so you can use objects without defining them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
$var = 'foo';
$this->$var->value();
```

Is equivalent to

```
$this->foo->value():
```

Similarly:

```
$var = 'bar';
$this->foo->$var();
```

Is equivalent to;

```
$this->foo->bar();
```

Comment: What's your position on curly braces? `$this->{$var}->value();` ?  I tend to like them because they make it a bit more visually clear that the method is a variable.

Comment: Cool thanks, that actually work.. do you also know if something like this is possible: $this->($this->pageClass->value)->value(); ?

Comment: wow thanks cale_b.. that did the trick :D I would upvote you two but sadly I can`t yet as new member ;)